# Is this a usual way of screening?

Tags: pre-screening

After my application as mechanical engineer I was contacted by the leader(manager) of the particular team to talk about the opportunity. We scheduled a day and the Skype talk was very good and he sounded like he was interested in me and didn't ask too hard questions. I was very passionate about the job and we had a very nice friendly talk. At the end he said he will arrange a face to face meeting together with other colleagues to show me the workplace and lab for the position.

I have never felt like I was in an interview and he didn't even mention HR process or HR person ect. Is this the new technique people are hired? Does anyone experience with such type of interview?

Comment: I was expecting HR and I was not thinking to be called to introduce their lab and equipment. I thought it is too early for that stage. Never happened to me that way "to me" at least.

Comment: You're talking to the hiring manager.  That's a positive.

Comment: Can a manager bypass HR when hiring?

Comment: No, a manager can't typically bypass HR, but HR will often just work in the background to make sure that the relevant laws and company policies are being followed. HR staff rarely have a technical background, so getting them deeply involved in the interviewing of technical staff is of limited usefulness.

Comment: Yeah, “HR screens your candidates” is the first thing I change when I go to a new management gig.  Zero benefit for skilled professionals.

Answer (score 4):

**Some companies let managers hire directly**

Some managers want to be part of the process for selecting their team members right from the beginning, so they handle all the functions which HR normally would. It gives them greater control of their team.

**You may also have been given advanced standing**

Sometimes a company has already decided that they are more likely to want you than not  (obviously contingent on you passing the final interview, background checks and not being an asshole). Whether it be a reference from your past, your public body of work, or just plain old desperation, the company could have already decided that you are a likely candidate for hire.

What happens then is that you can get an abbreviated interview process which is less focused on making you prove yourself and more about convincing you to come onboard if you are offered the job. Because they are already interested, they skip the HR chat stage and move directly to the interview with a manager stage.

I had a friend refer me for a job at a company he worked for. Because I was referred, they skipped the typical Hackerrank automated assessment, the HR interview, and even the one on one assessment to put me into the final round interview with the entire team I would have been working with.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For me I felt that he is really interested(saying like you can do it, you will have enough time ect.), But I dont want to get frustrated, so I dont want to expect so much. But Im extremely excited about the outcome.

Comment: +1 Many companies regard HR interviewing for technical positions like a mechanical engineer as a waste of time. HR might not even be qualified to review references for a technical position. At the last 5 jobs I held HR only showed up at the end to discuss pay and benefits.

Answer (score -1):

Really hard to tell if this is usual. I have experienced a similar process at my current job. IMHO smaller firms are more likely to take a risk with applicants, bypassing the usual vetting process one has to endure.